# Multirepository pipeline in python

Tags: python, git, package, pipeline

I have one pipeline build in python that consists in many different steps. Each step is an individual process that can be run standalone. I want each step/process to be in a different repository so each developer can focus in his project. The pipeline just will import all projects/code and run the pipeline. What is the best way to organize the code and import all the individual projects in the main pipeline projects?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/). You can use a python operator or bash operator to execute basically all your code separately. For example use a bash operator to update the github code and then use another bash operator to execute it.